# Can I register my app as an alarm clock handler?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I'm working on a streaming radio app, which can play one of a predefined set of stations. I would like to integrate this with existing alarm clock apps, without having to build any alarm functionality into the app itself.

When the alarm goes off, the radio should start playing. Ideally it should play a station chosen by the user beforehand, but I'll settle for storing the last used station and playing that instead.

I looked through the [common intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) available on Android, but there doesn't seem to be anything appropriate. In particular:

- `INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH` requires a free-form search query, which doesn't seem appropriate.
- `ACTION_VIEW` requires a URL. I could use the stream URL of the radio station, or maybe come up with a custom URL scheme like `my-radio-app://station-id`, but then how do I convince generic alarm clock apps to show the user a list of available stations?

To approach it from the other end, I looked at existing alarm clock apps. The stock app doesn't do any integrations. The Sleep as Android app that I use can trigger Spotify, but I think that's a custom built integration. It also seems to read and list all music tracks from the SD card.

Am I trying to do the impossible? Are these intents just not standardised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to integrate this with existing alarm clock apps, without having to build any alarm functionality into the app itself.

I would be rather surprised if many alarm clock apps support this.

> When the alarm goes off, the radio should start playing

That is only a piece of the required integration. Of note, when the user snoozes or stops the alarm, the radio should stop playing.

> how do I convince generic alarm clock apps to show the user a list of available stations?

Some alarm clock apps might allow the user to select a piece of audio to play back as the alarm "ringtone". Those apps could get that audio in one of a few ways. The one that you could hook into would be `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. You could have an activity that implements an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, for some appropriate `audio` MIME type, where your activity returns a `Uri` to the audio. However, that `Uri` would then have to point to a stream that could be played by `MediaPlayer`, as that is how the alarm clock app is most likely going to play that audio (directly or via `setSound()` on a `Notification.Builder`). This is the closest that you are going to get to something that is supported, and in this case, you are not playing the audio, but at most transcoding some stream into something that `MediaPlayer` can play.

My guess is that this is not what you have in mind.

> Are these intents just not standardised?

I am not quite certain what you expect an `Intent` to do in this case. For example, the `Intent` cannot be used to start an activity to play the audio, because your activity often cannot be displayed (user screen is locked) and the alarm clock app cannot stop the music when the user snoozes or stops the alarm.

There is no standard mechanism in Android for one app to ask another app to start and stop playing audio. You are welcome to invent a convention for this and convince alarm clock developers to implement it.

Comment: True, I'd need a bit more integration than just starting to play, but decided to keep it simple initially... apparently that's already hard enough ;) Thank you for confirming my doubts. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` could indeed be used for selecting the particular stream, but of course requires cooperation from both apps. Pity. I would expect that an `Intent` can somehow be used to start playback even when the device is locked. But as you say, it doesn't seem to be standardised, and I'm not inclined to try as this is just a hobby project.